# Need Help Creating An SSRS Report with Grouped Data

Tags: reporting-services

For simplicity sake, let's assume my DataSet looks like this:

```
SELECT C.CategoryName, C.Description, P.ProductName, P.UnitPrice, P.ReorderLevel
FROM Categories C
JOIN Products P
ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID

And for simplicity let's say the data I get back looks like this:
BEVERAGES   | GREAT DRINKS | SODA     | 2.99 | 1
BEVERAGES   | GREAT DRINKS | VODKA    | 9.99 | 9
SNACKS      | GREAT SNACKS | PRETZELS | 1.99 | 1
SNACKS      | GREAT SNACKS | CHIPS    | 1.99 | 1
```

And let's say I want my report to look like this:

```
BEVERAGES - GREAT DRINKS


PRODUCT NAME      PRICE
VODKA             9.99
SODA              2.99

- PAGE BREAK -


SNACKS - GREAT SNACKS

PRODUCT NAME    | PRICE
PRETZELS        | 1.99
CHIPS           | 1.99
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to run only one query?

If they are on two different pages, why not run two separate queries and adding a WHERE P.ProductName = "something"  Or you could do a GROUP BY to get the different groups and run the WHERE clause according to that result set.

```
SELECT C.CategoryName, C.Description, P.ProductName AS pname, P.UnitPrice, P.ReorderLevel
FROM Categories C
JOIN Products P
ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
ORDER BY P.ProductName
```

Psuedo Code

```
var hold = ''
foreach result as r
  if hold != r[pname] then call function to display product listing header
  hold = r[pname]
  display product information and pricing
```

Comment: Let's assume I'm running one query. I basically want to group some information about each Category, and then show a table below it with the relevant results.

Comment: Well, couldn't you just add an ORDER BY P.ProductName at the end?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pseudo code... would that be in SQL or SSRS? I'm really thinking that this in essence some form of drill down report-- but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 0):

It took some time, but basically I think I was trying to do a sub report. I used a List created a group for CategoryId. I then created a subreport which was passed the CategoryId as a parameter. Worked out well.